# Avoid Try Catch Stements with custom ErrorHandler class - C#

Tags: c#, .net, error-handling

I have a class which exposes some functionality,
and I want to ensure exceptions will be handled by a custom ErrorHandler class.

Currently I can achieve this by a try / catch statement per each method, and process the exception by the error handler there.

My question is if there is a better way / design pattern to do it.

Code:

```
public class BasicErrorHandler
{
    public void ProcessException(Exception ex)
    {
        //Does error handling stuff
    }
}

public class Manager
{
    BasicErrorHandler _errorHandler;

    public Manager()
    {
        _errorHandler = new BasicErrorHandler();
    }

    public void MethodA()
    {
        try
        {
            //Does Something    
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            _errorHandler.ProcessException(ex);
        }            
    }

    public void MethodB()
    {
        try
        {
            //Does Something Else
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            _errorHandler.ProcessException(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @DeblatonJean-Philippe I didn't understand your comment.

Comment: @Y.S - Ignore it. Its rude and unconstructive and ive flagged it as such. [We stopped linking to LMGTFY many years ago!](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255397/lmgtfy-link-cant-be-added)

Comment: And also why do we imply MVC 5?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In keeping with [DRY principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself), you could just wrap your `try...catch` logic into into own method which takes a predicate of the actual work to do:

```
public class Manager
{
    BasicErrorHandler _errorHandler;

    public Manager()
    {
        _errorHandler = new BasicErrorHandler();
    }

    public void MethodA()
    {
        DoWork( () => {
            // do something interesting here
        });
    }

    public void MethodB()
    {
        DoWork( () => {
            // do something else interesting here
        });  
    }

    private void DoWork(Action action)
    {
        try
        {
            action();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            _errorHandler.ProcessException(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's the one I was looking for, thanks alot. I'll accept this as the answer because here in oppose to JCLs answer, the error handler is addressed in one place and not in each method, which to my opinion is a better design. but I +1 both answers to show my appreciation.

Comment: Also here the error hanler doesnt invoke the funtionality, but wraps it

Comment: @Jamiec just another sub question, if the methods werent voids, and had different return types and input parameters, would you still go with this design?

Comment: @Y.S - possibly, but it might get a little more complex, with multiple versions of `DoWork` or perhaps generics to determine return types. If you want to update your question with more detail I could give it a go.

Comment: @Y.S. you could use a `T DoWork<T>(Func<T> action)` for that, and just return the data. Just take into account that exceptions will be caught and your function may return data after having an exception. You may want to rethrow, but it depends on your actual requirements

Comment: @Jamiec no need, I can take it to the implementation phase myself, thanks for the tip and heads up.

Answer (score 3):

I've crafted this quickly and without thinking too much in the implications, but if you want to avoid all the try/catch blocks, you could do something like:

```
public class BasicErrorHandler
{
    public void ProcessException(Exception ex)
    {
        //Does error handling stuff
    }

    public void Do(Action act)
    {
        try
        {
            act();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ProcessException(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

And then use it like:

```
public class Manager
{
    BasicErrorHandler _errorHandler;

    public Manager()
    {
        _errorHandler = new BasicErrorHandler();
    }

    public void MethodA()
    {
        _errorHandler.Do(() => {
            //Does Something    
        });
    }

    public void MethodB()
    {
        _errorHandler.Do(() => {
            //Does Something Else
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Basically same answer as mine, but mere seconds faster. The thing I *dont* like about this is that the error handler should just be the error handler, it shouldnt know how to "Do" anything else. SRP!

Comment: @Jamiec you are right, I was editing my answer to move it to the class (before seeing your answer), but I got a phone call and you came faster :-). I'll leave it like this with the comment though, yours is definitely a better answer

Answer (score 2):

Design patterns are there to solve a problem. Which problem are you trying to solve? What is wrong with the Try Catch blocks?

Only thing I can imagine is you want to have more clean code. Some answers suggest a helper method with an action. Given the helper methods that encapsulate a delegate: Do consider the impact on your stack trace and debugging sessions using these delegates. It might make logging etc more hard to understand.

If your intend is to do separation of concern, I would say If you can't handle it, just don't catch the exception. Let the class invoking the method handle it. If you insist to have a handler in your class, I would suggest Inversion of Control. That way, your class is not in control of determining which class should handle its exceptions.

Comment: Given the OP's comment on my answer that their "real-world" is actually more complex than this question, I think you're spot-on here!

Comment: I pretty much (despite my answer) agree with this. I don't think methods should blindly catch all exceptions... exceptions are there to be thrown to *the user of that method*, not to be caught by the method itself. So unless the error manager is re-throwing (or the requirements are that those methods should never fail without the user of those methods knowing if they have failed or not), I don't think there's a "good pattern" to follow here

Answer (score 1):

Rx .net is for You. Advanced error handling gives You the ability to highly customize Your error handling. Check out the [pages about that](http://www.introtorx.com/content/v1.0.10621.0/11_AdvancedErrorHandling.html).

For example:

```
var source = new Subject<int>();
var result = source.Catch<int, TimeoutException>(tx=>Observable.Return(-1));
result.Dump("Catch");
source.OnNext(1);
source.OnNext(2);
source.OnError(new ArgumentException("Fail!"));
```

You'll get the following output:

```
Catch-->1
Catch-->2
Catch failed-->Fail!
```

The number of retries, the handling of how much time a method can take, everything can be configured.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at it, although I'm also looking for an answer that addresses the problem without using external library, but rather using a design pattern for error handling. +1.

Answer (score 1):

The following is an Aspect oriented method of soling the problem, this makes use of [PostSharp](https://www.postsharp.net/) to do the weaving.

```
[Serializable]
public class HandleExceptionsAttribute : OnExceptionAspect {
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="HandleExceptionsAttribute"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    public HandleExceptionsAttribute() {
        AspectPriority = 1;
    }

    public override void OnException(MethodExecutionArgs args) {
        //Suppress the current transaction to ensure exception is not rolled back
        using (var s = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Suppress)) {
            //Log exception
            using (var exceptionLogContext = new ExceptionLogContext()) {
                exceptionLogContext.Set<ExceptionLogEntry>().Add(new ExceptionLogEntry(args.Exception));
                exceptionLogContext.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }
}

[HandleExceptions]
public class YourClass {

}
```